# Maven include/assemble packaged static html project in war

Tags: maven, war, multi-module

I have war archive which has its own xhtmls. js, html, css and so on in its webapp directory.
It packages fine with maven. 
I have to include another static component which is pure html+js. How to do that? 
I try packaging the static project into jar file and add dependency to the war but it is placed in WEB-INF/lib/ as a jar file so it is not public accessable. 
I need to be in the root of my war like the other xhtml and static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to [use a war overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-overlay.html) and have multiple war projects.

If you can't change the packaging type of the static project (from jar to war), you may want to use something like [embedded-resources](https://bitbucket.org/bmeurant/embedded-resources). This approach is less standard but pretty efficient.